# Summary calculation based on Year in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, calculation

I need help trying to get a percentage of change based on the current year and 90 days prior to the current date.
The report is a compilation of current market rent, divided by the Previous market rent to get the growth. I want to only summarize based on the current year, not any previous years.
I am able to calculate the percentage, but when I add the criteria for the year, I get an Error when running the report.
I have tried to add this as a detail record as well but I still get the same error.

Here is my expression for the Current Year (haven't tried 90 days yet):

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!MarketPast.Value)<> 0 AND 
YEAR(Format(CDATE(LEFT(Fields!LeaseFrm.Value, 12))="mm/dd/yyyy"))=YEAR(NOW),
((SUM(Fields!rent.Value)/SUM(Fields!MarketPast.Value)) -1),0)
```

The report should look like the below:

[image: Trade Out Report]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can remove the FORMAT and `="mm/dd/yyyy")` to get it working right. The FORMAT is just converting the CDATE back to a string date but it needs a comma and not an equals sign before the format.

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!MarketPast.Value) <> 0 
        AND YEAR(CDATE(LEFT(Fields!LeaseFrm.Value, 12))) = YEAR(NOW)
    ,SUM(Fields!rent.Value) / SUM(Fields!MarketPast.Value) - 1
    , 0
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It worked correctly. Will the same work when I count back 90 days from the current date?

Comment: @TammyRobinson - ASSuMEing that you're going to change the Year comparison to `CDATE(blah blah) >= Today.AddDays(-90)` or something like that.